# How can I compare 2 dates in a Where statement while using NoRM for MongoDB on C#?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver, norm

I have a table in Mongo. One of the fields is a DateTime. I would like to be able to get all of the records that are only for a single day (i.e. 9/3/2011).

If I do something like this:

```
 var list = (from c in col
             where c.PublishDate == DateTime.Now
             select c).ToList();
```

Then it doesn't work because it is using the time in the comparison. Normally I would just compare the ToShortDateString() but NoRM does not allow me to use this.

Thoughts?

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is normally to calculate the start datetime and end datetime for the date in question and then query for values in that range.

```
var start = DateTime.Now.Date;
var end = start.AddDays(1);
...
```

But you'd also be well advised to switch to the official C# driver now.  You should also use UTC datetimes in your database (but that gets more complicated).

Comment: We use LINQ heavily so right now the official driver is not an option. Hope that changes with future releases.

Comment: Really it's not that good a fit for MongoDB with the advanced modification capabilities it has like $push, $inc, ... http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Comment: I looked into the official driver...the problem is, it doesn't work in a medium trust environment which is a requirement right now.